# Excel: AverageIf Multiple Criteria, sometimes one criteria will be empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula that finds the average of multiple criteria even if one of the criteria happens to be blank. For instance, I want to find the average of how many apples and oranges, even if oranges happens to be 0 or blank.

I could do the average of both averages of apples and oranges, but average of averages is not completely accurate.

I have a formula that I was told should work, but when I put it in, it says

> #N/A: Wrong number of arguments to IF, Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments.

If I can have help making it work, it seems like it is what I am looking for. I am open to other ideas as well.

```
=AVERAGE(IF('Data'!C:D,"Item 1","Item 2",'Data'!D:D))
```

Comment: Adding some context to why your posted formula failed…  the excel IF function has only three arguments:  (1) The condition that is either true or false;  (2) The result you want if it is true; and (3) the result you want if it is false.  You have 4 arguments, and none one of them are a condition that will be either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to tackle this is using the `AVERAGEIFS()` function. Assuming your data is stored in the range `A1:B4`, you need to put the following formula in `C2` and copy it down:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A2:B2,A2:B2,"<>#N/A",A2:B2,"<>0")
```

The first argument reflects the average range. The second argument reflects the range for the first criteria, which is the exclusion of `#N/A` values. The similar idea applies to the exclusion of 0.

If you just want to exclude `#N/A` values a simple `AVERAGEIF()` approach suffices. In this case use the following approach:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A4:B4,"<>#N/A")
```

Data and Output:

[image: data and output]